# jPlayer does not play MP3 files

Tags: flash, jplayer

I tried to set up a playlist with jPlayer, like [this demo](http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/latest/demo-02.htm) shows.

You can find my code [here](http://pgdegans.webfactional.com/).

I've checked the `playList` var, everything is okay (it contains all mp3 URLs for each `<article>` element which represents a track).

The swfPath to jPlayer.swf is correct too.

So I really don't understand where is the problem ? Any idea ?

Thank you. :-)

Comment: Well what *is* the problem?  You do not describe that which does not work. And on your sight, I could play an mp3 (and it was really nice too; who is that?)

Comment: Using Firefox 3.5.8, Opera 10 or IE7, the MP3 files are not played at this adress : http://pgdegans.webfactional.com/ However I don't understand why because all settings are correct (the mp3 files are valid, the jPlayer.swf is valid and in my playlist.js I've set a valid ``swfpath``).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jplayer.swf is not on the same domain as the rest of the code.